# Regenerate /etc/default/grub

Tags: grub2

I accidentally wiped `/etc/default/grub` with a mistyped `:w !sudo tee %`. Is there a way to regenerate its content? Is the original available somewhere to copy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly, that file `/etc/default/grub/` doesn't seem to be provided by any package. I used `dpkg -S /etc/default/grub`, but it failed. However, you can copy the content of the default file from below. This file is same for Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: God bless you. Do you know where I can find the original source?

Comment: I have given the file's content in the answer. copy the contents and create a new file in '/etc/default' directory with 'grub' name. paste the content in the file and save it. note- you need root permission to do so

Comment: Content is still the same on 15.10

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge grub-pc
sudo apt-get install grub-pc
```

Comment: Actually, this should be the accepted answer. I also highly appreciate @Anwar's answer, but this one will probably work in future versions, too. Surprisingly, `aptitude purge grub-pc` and `aptitude install grub-pc` did *not* do the trick for me, while `apt-get remove --purge grub-pc` and `apt-get install gruc-pc` did.