# Unable to boot to GUI from a Text Window

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, gui, cuda

I have installed nvidia cuda drivers and toolkit in ubuntu 12.04 as given in the book **CUDA Programming**    A Developer’s Guide to Parallel Computing with GPUs by **Shane Cook**.

I have used these commands

```
sudo chmod +w /etc/default/grub

sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the following lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

to

```
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"
```

Now update grub using

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then type

`sudo sh cuda_5.5.22_linux.32.run`

(I have downloaded **cuda_5.5.22_linux_32.run** from nvidia.com)

Drivers and toolkit have been installed successfully

Now I have changed etc/defualt/grub to its previous state i.e.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

and update it and then

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

but now I am unable to go back to GUI mode I am getting only a blank screen

Please let me know where I am getting wrong and how to resolve it.

Comment: did you save that file and update the grub by `sudo update-grub` command?

Comment: check your grub file will look like this http://askubuntu.com/a/277745/202806.

Comment: yes  I have updated it @Avinash Raj

Comment: @SaadRafey See the link by Avinash