# Can't run 'sudo update-grub' after making changes to grub file

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.10

`sudo update-grub` gives this error message:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 26: /etc/default/grub: want: not found
```

I deleted the commented out line 26 of the `/etc/default/grub` file and I got:

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 25: /etc/default/grub: want: not found
```

I am trying to turn on command line boot, so I can see what's going on at boot time.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1452695/edit) your question and add the contents of your `/etc/default/grub` file?  It will be kind of hard to come up with an answer when we cannot see what each line contains.  There could be a simple quote issue where the quotes get copied off of websites that are not the standard " from the keyboard.  Thank you!

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
 (THIS IS LINE 26 of my GRUB FILE)
# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1452695/edit) and don't use comments for it.  Also, please add the entire contents of your `/etc/default/grub` file since it is seeing the word `want` at the start of a line or that is not commented out and that is why it is failing.

Comment: Line 26 looks like it is `# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux` but you might have pressed enter or something, but that is where it looks like you are getting your error from.  Remember that blank lines in a file still count as lines.

Comment: I deleted evrything commented out in the file. My grub file is 9 lines long. I get this ralph@ralph-hp-workstation-xw6200:/$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Comment: You need a new `/etc/default/grub` file.  Too many errors in it.  Follow https://askubuntu.com/a/910127/231142 and if you only have 1 OS that should be all you need.  If you have more than one, you will need to add the line of `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false` to your `/etc/default/grub` file so that it will detect other OSes on your system and add them to the grub boot menu.

Comment: Thatnks Terrance. grub-update worked. Now I want to show the boot process as it boots?

Comment: Thanks Terrance for your help. I know have it running. Cheers!